# There is a better way to validate in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

The example below is how I'm authenticating my users today:

```
def create
    if is_internal_request(params[:authenticity_token])
        @user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])

        if @user
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            render :json => true
        else
            render :json => 
            { 
                error:
                {
                    code: 1, 
                    message: t('globals.errors.authentication.user-not-found') 
                } 
            }.to_json
        end
    end
end
```

Pay attention to this fragment:

```
render :json => 
{ 
    error:
    {
        code: 1, 
        message: t('globals.errors.authentication.user-not-found') 
    } 
}.to_json
```

Based on it, I want to know if it's organized and solid. I mean, is that something in the edge of the right way?

### Forward thinking

Lets suppose that there are some places in my application that check about user's e-mail availability. I want to be DRY and reuse that verification every time I need to use it. If the way that I'm doing the validation (as below) isn't *"perfect"* at all, how can I create a validation layer that can be useful every time I want?

I mean, instead of create and recreate that fragment of code each time that I want to validate, what's the best way to do something like this?:

```
email = params[:email]

unless email_is_available(email)
    render :json => { message: 'E-mail isn't available' }
end
```

With "*what's the best way to do something like this?*" I'm saying, **where I have to place `email_is_available` function to get it working right?**

Answer (score 0):

Every Controller can access `ApplicationController` methods as they inherit from it.

Anyways, I'd recommend using a gem like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for a more complete solution.

GL & HF.

Comment: Talking about good practices (pay attention: *good practices*, not patterns): is a good practice to place validation behaviors within the `ApplicationController`?

Comment: It depends on the extension/modularity/etc of your code if it deserves a module of its own or not.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
  if @user.valid?
    render :json => true
  else
    error_hash = {}
    @user.errors.each{|k,v| error_hash[k] = "#{k.capitalize} #{v}"}
    #this will give you a hash like {"email" => "Email is not available"}
    render :json => {:errors => error_hash}
  end
```

At the client end, you will get this back (eg as an object called `data`), see if there is a value for data.errors and then display the various error messages to the user.

Note i haven't plugged in any translation stuff but you can do that :)

Comment: `@user.errors` comes from the validation flags of `user` model, right?

Comment: Yes.  This is populated as a side-effect of calling @user.valid?

Comment: We have a problem here, because neither `@user.valid` nor `@user.errors` exists.

Comment: its `.valid?` (with a question mark), not `.valid`.  Although it may have changed in your version of Rails, check the appropriate API doc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a look at Ryan Bates' Railscast on authentication from scratch. It walks you through all the issues and is much lighter weight than relying on something as big and heavy as Devise.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch